# Using get_post_type with a custom URL format?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type with rewritten URLs.
Slug is: top-news
Rewrite is: top/news

I have a function that updates the last modified date whenever a comment is posted that works correctly (found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/269694)), however I want this to apply only to this custom post type.

I tried wrapping the function in:

```
if ( is_singular( 'top-news' ) ) {
}
```

and also with:

```
if( get_post_type() == 'top-news' ) {
}
```

However these don't seem to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And how does that function look? When do you call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing something in the `wp_insert_comment` hook, then you should use the 2nd argument, `$comment_object`, if you want to know anything about the post the comment was for. `$comment_object` is a `WP_Comment` object that has a `$comment_post_ID` property that has the ID of the post the comments is for. You can use that to determine its post type. The URL structure is completely irrelevant.

```
function wpse_304105_update_time( $comment_id, $comment_object ) {
    $post_id = $comment_object->comment_post_ID;

    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'top-news' ) {
        // Update post time.
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'wpse_304105_update_time', 99, 2 );
```